# How to sort in asending order the inputed 3 numbers

Tags: javascript

I wrote the following JavaScript code to sort in ascending order the numbers. The numbers are taken by the user input. Here I declared x, y, and z are the variables for the user input.

When I input the values 2, 3 and 4 respectively, the output is correct. But when I input the values (2,4,3) (3,2,4) (3,4,2) (4,3,2) (4,2,3) The output is wrong. Why that that the expected output is not printed ?
    
    
    
    
    var x,y,z;

```
x = parseInt(prompt("Enter num"));
y = parseInt(prompt("Enter num"));
z = parseInt(prompt("Enter num"));


if ((x<y)&&(x<z))
    {
        document.write(x);
             if (y<z)
                {
                    document.write(y);
                    document.write(z);
                }
    }

else if ((y<z)&&(y<x))
    {
        document.write(y);
            if (z<x)
                {
                    document.write(z);
                    document.write(x);
                }
    }

else if ((z<x)&&(z<y))
    {
        document.write(z);
            if (x<y)
                {
                    document.write(x);
                    document.write(y);
                }
    }
```

```
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you may consider an array for the values.

Comment: Sorry, I don't like to do in array

Comment: You don't need to use array as such. But, you can use the array to sort and get the values form it and use it however you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your original question with three variables, you need for every main comparison an else part and write the reverse order of the variables.

```js
var x = parseInt(prompt("Enter num")),
    y = parseInt(prompt("Enter num")),
    z = parseInt(prompt("Enter num"));

if (x < y && x < z) {
    document.write(x);
    if (y < z) {
        document.write(y);
        document.write(z);
    } else {                  // add this
        document.write(z);
        document.write(y);
    }
} else if (y < z && y < x) {
    document.write(y);
    if (z < x) {
        document.write(z);
        document.write(x);
    } else {                  // add this
        document.write(x);
        document.write(z);
    }
} else {                      // you can skip the comparison here,
    document.write(z);        // because there is no other possibillity
    if (x < y) {
        document.write(x);
        document.write(y);
    } else {                  // add this
        document.write(y);
        document.write(x);
    }
}
```

You could collect the values in an array and sort it then by the numerical value.

```js
var length = 3,
    array = [];

while(array.length<length) {
    array.push(+prompt("Enter num"));
}
array.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; });
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Is there any way to do without array? (Do in normal way)

Comment: Array is the "normal" way. They are made for this exact situation. You should have a really really good reason to not use them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the build in `sort()` function to do this...

```js
x = parseInt(prompt("Enter num"));
y = parseInt(prompt("Enter num"));
z = parseInt(prompt("Enter num"));

var sorted = [x,y,z].sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
})
console.log('sorted: ',sorted.join(' '))
```

Comment: you sort strings, not numbers.

Comment: @NinaScholz Didn't you see the `parseInt()`?

Comment: [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) without callback is sorting strings.

Comment: @NinaScholz Thanks for the info. Anyways, the return value is a `int`.

Comment: please insert 1, 11, 2  and watch the result.

Comment: @NinaScholz Thanks mate. Learnt something. Updated the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array from the values, and use Array.prototype.sort():

```js
var x = parseInt(prompt("Enter num"), 10);
var y = parseInt(prompt("Enter num"), 10);
var z = parseInt(prompt("Enter num"), 10);

var arr = [x,y,z];
console.log(arr.sort(function(a,b) { return a-b; }))
```